# List of Model's Field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been looking at the Rails documentation and can't find this.

Lets say I have a Model `User` with field `strength`.

How do I get a list of all `strength`s for every instance of the model object in an array?

list_of_str = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc..]

I know that you can call `User.all` and iterate through each of their strength fields and append them to a list but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of elegancy are you looking for? You could get array of all `strengthes` by `User.all.map(&:strength)`. Is it elegant way? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.pluck 'strength'
```

New in rails 3.2 if my memory is correct

You can use

```
User.uniq.pluck 'strength'
```

If you need to avoid duplicates, and you can also combine this with scopes and conditions, for example

```
User.where(...).pluck 'strength'
```

Comment: definitely the right way to do it - doesn't put unnecessary load on the db, doesn't instantiate a bunch of ORM objects, just runs `select users.strength from users` and turns the output into a simple string array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the select method for that, it generates a query where only the values of the desired field are retrieved (which is faster than loading all model data from the database):

```
User.select(:strength)
```

This still returns an array of model-objects, so you have to use map to get an array of the values only:

```
User.select(:strength).map(&:strength)
```

The creation of the model object will be slower than just querying the database for the values, but using raw SQL should be avoided if performance is not critical in this place.

**Edit**: There is an even better way (`pluck`), see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really after the distinct `strength`s then:

```
User.select('distinct strength').pluck(:strength)
```

will get them. If you don't care about duplicates then Frederick Cheung's plain `pluck` would be a good idea.

Comment: awesome! didn't know about `pluck`. But I think `User.uniq.pluck(:strength)` won't create duplicates and doesn't force you to pass extra-SQL as string.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke: True, the `.uniq.pluck` will end up doing a simple `select distinct strength from users`.